# Why is "collect a coin" ungrammatical?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I'm on the topic of countability and an example in my book says that "collect a coin" is ungrammatical, and that you say "collect coins" instead. But why? Is it because "collecting" is not appropriate for one coin?

Comment: Because the book has no sense of imagination.  You can definitely collect a coin, add it to your piggy bank, then collect another.

Comment: If you collect a coin, then collect another, haven't you 'collected coins' rather than 'collected a coin'?

Comment: Perhaps the book is arguing that it's technically not a collection until you possess more than one of some object.

Comment: Your book is wrong.

Comment: @Roaring Fish: No, you've collected a coin twice, in two separate acts.

Comment: @jamesqf aren't both true? After twice eating an egg, after all, one has eaten two eggs.

Comment: @jamesqf ~ okay... you collected a coin twice - how many coins do you have now?

Comment: The book may make an argument that *collect a coin* is *illogical,* which I disagree with, but I can see how someone might hold that position. Nobody would think it is *ungrammatical.*  For example, is generally incorrect to say "the door is extremely closed," but it's perfectly grammatical, it's just illogical.

Comment: @RoaringFish perhaps you have one coin, having collected the same coin twice, having relinquished possession (or perhaps having dropped it) between the two acts of collection.

Comment: @phoog ~ ridiculously convoluted examples are not an argument, unless you think think pigs can fly because "ah but... if you fire a pig from a catapult it flies"

Comment: @RoaringFish I find my example considerably less convoluted than the catapult example, but okay. It was much more of a joke than an attempt at argument, anyway.

Comment: *Collect* can mean fetch (at least in AmE), so *collect a coin* makes sense in that context.

Comment: Do you have more context to this phrase? E.g. *Collect a coin from the front desk.* or *The coin collector collected a coin from his correspondent.*

Comment: Could you please cite the complete "rule" from the book, the example "collect coins" and provide the book's title and which level of English it is aimed for, please. I suspect you have made too harsh a summary.

Comment: "Collect a coin" is ungrammatical for the same reason that ["more perfect"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+perfect&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20perfect%3B%2Cc0) is ungrammatical.

Comment: I think the line between *a coin* and *a collection* of coins is blurred, kinda like [sorites paradox.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox)

Comment: Normally to collect is connected with several things. "to collect a coin" (a single thing) just sounds a bit queer.

Comment: @Lawrence ~ the correct form offered by the OP is 'collect coins', which makes it clear that the sense is collect as a hobby, not collect as in fetch though that alternative sense may be what is confusing the OP. How often do people with a single coin say "I have a collection of one coin" in preference to "I have a coin"?

Answer (score 4):

When discussing the **collect**ion of popular **collect**ables such as coins, there is an understandable tendency to blur the different meanings of the verb **collect**, making it possible to find and imagine examples of collecting a single coin that are neither ungrammatical  nor illogical and that are neither convoluted nor imaginary in the world of numismatics; and this is why I would suggest that the time spent on the topic of countability by your book would have perhaps been better spent explaining why “numismatics” is “coin collecting” and “numismatists” are “coin collectors” (and not  “coin**s** collecting” and “coin**s** collectors,” respectively) than by picking on the grammaticality of “collect a coin.”

An astute and well received (currently +3) comment above correctly notes that coin collectors would “say [they] **bought** a coin for [their] collection, not that [they] collected a coin for [their] collection” to correctly show that “collected a coin” would not be used with “for a collection.”
However, just as “collected” is not the right verb in that particular phrase, neither is “bought” the perfect one, for a coin is often “**acquired** or **gotten** for a collection” by “**getting** it in” or “**culling** it from” circulation (pocket change) and not always by purchasing it.

Please note that I bring this up, not at all to be nit-picky with that good comment, but rather as simply an introduction to the following attempt to try to explain why the “natural tendency to blur [and perhaps even overlap] the different meanings of the verb *collect*” mentioned in paragraph 1 exists and how it is perhaps its existence that gives rise to logical and non-convoluted uses of "collecting one or a [single] coin” in the discussion of coin collecting:

Both the “getting” in “getting a coin in circulation” and the “culling” in “culling a coin from circulation” have close connections with the verb “collect” that, in my opinion, cause this blurring/overlapping.

Regarding “getting,” ‘Cambridge Dictionaries Online’ uses “**To get** [and keep]” in its entry for “collect” relevant to coin collecting (cf: the use of the plural “things” and the example using the plural “stamps”) and in the entry relating to the word’s “fetching” notion, “Get” is presented in parenthesis right after the word, which I interpret as meaning that they’re synonymous or nearly so.

> [**collect**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/collect)
>   verb (AS A HOBBY)
>   A2 [T]  to get and keep things of one type such
>   as stamps or coins as a hobby:
>      She collects dolls.
>     So when did
>   you start collecting antique glass?
>   **collect** verb **(GET)**
>    A2 [T] mainly UK to go to a place and bring someone or something away from it:
>      Your shoes will be
>   repaired and ready for you to collect on Thursday.
>      I'll collect
>   you from the station.

(from 'Cambridge Dictionaries Online' with emphasis added)

As for “culling,” ‘The ‘American Heritage Roget’s Thesaurus’ connects “cull” directly with “collect” (arguably used with a singular [some]thing), in definition 2:

> [**cull**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cull) verb
>   2. To collect (some**thing**) **bit by bit** [or coin by coin?].

(from ‘The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus’ via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex’, with emphasis and bracketed question added)

As a numismatist (although neither a grammarian nor a logician) and with these connections between ‘getting,’ ‘culling,’ and ‘collecting ’ (all with connections themselves with numismatics) in mind, I find nothing illogical, ungrammatical, convoluted, or imaginary in the following examples where “collected” is used with a singular coin in contexts not requiring a trip to the post office:

> [He] still has [**the** first **coin** he
>   **collected**](http://digital.ipcprintservices.com/article/Contributors/443943/0/article.html)
>   from circulation (**a** 1917-S Mercury dime).

(from ‘The Numismatist’ — August 2010, via ‘digital.ipcprintservices[dot]com’)

> [Often times a collector will **collect a single coin** of each year
>   of coins for a particular design type of coins.
>
>     A TYPE coin
>   collection is different from a DATE coin collection, because the
>   collector is trying to **collect ONE coin** of each design type for a
>   particular area of U.S.
>   Coins.](http://www.coinweek.com/coins/coin-collecting-strategies-2/coin-collecting-strategies-what-should-i-collect-tips-for-building-a-meaningful-set-of-u-s-coins/)

(from paragraphs 5 and 6, respectively of a ‘Coin World’ article discussing coin collecting strategies)

> I [**collected a
>   coin**](https://books.google.com/books?id=vqTRBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=%22collected+a+coin+from%22&source=bl&ots=AXUJC5s9QD&sig=fkNTD9PLEYnnLkeWBTS4igXG6A8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjumLOXw83LAhWGpB4KHStEBCkQ6AEIMDAH#v=onepage&q=%22collected%20a%20coin%20from%22&f=false)
>   from each country we visited.

(from ‘Events in the Life of an Ordinary Man’ by Richard R. Pariseau, via Google Books’)

Comment: Bravo!  (My modest collection is ancient Greek silver, which I rarely find in my supermarket change.)

Comment: Good answer, except that I think that at least for those of us who don't collect things as a hobby, the second meaning (collect those shoes, collect a debt, &c) is what comes first to mind.

Comment: If I buy a coin for my collection, and then go to the owner's home to pick it up, I collect the coin.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, and I see that as a use of “collect” in its pure “fetching/retrieving/getting” sense after the coin’s purchase, whereas I see the three examples cited in my answer as using it (misusing it, perhaps but using it nonetheless) in a possible hybrid sense of the word’s “as a hobby” and its “get/fetch” meanings, perhaps especially appropriate when the coin isn’t purchased but is instead plucked from circulation. In the first and third examples especially, it could be that “collect” is being used to mean “fetched from circulation.”

Comment: ' The first coin he got'...'get a single coin of each year'...'get one coin of each design'...'get a coin from each country'. The sense is to get or to fetch, not a hobby. Plus, as a first must have a second and there is more than one year, design, and country those collectors almost certainly have collections of more than one coin - they 'collect coins'.

Comment: @RoaringFish Thanks! You know, I’m not at all sure why I continue to do so, but I’ve combed through the OP’s question and its title multiple times and I continue to wrongly interpret it as asking why/whether “collect a coin” is ungrammatical and not whether a coin collection can consist of just one coin. In fact, it’s gotten so bad that I’m not even capable of finding just one “collection” hidden among the question’s many words. Hopefully it's just that my “read-between-the-lines” glasses need adjusting or something!

Answer (score 3):

The short and simple answer is that one coin is not a collection by definition. A collection has to be more that one item. From [Oxford Dictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collect):

*Bring or gather together (a number of things)*

There is a grey area in that collect also has a sense of 'fetch'. From the same source:

*Call for and take away; fetch*

This sense is basically gathering together the things that you own, as in collect your mail from the post office, or collect your certificate when you graduate.  In this sense it is possible that you may, for example, have bought a rare coin which you could then collect from the post office.

Comment: A coin collection has to start somewhere; you can start it with a single coin.

Comment: @GregLee in other words the "number" in the definition's *a number of things* could be one.

Comment: One would be 'a thing', not 'a number of things'. A single item is not a collection: "to get (things) from different places and bring them together" (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collect) Note the plural 'things'.

Comment: You can definitely collect a coin from the post office as Roaring Fish said in his last sentence.  You might also have left a coin with an appraiser (or your grandfather) and go to collect the coin from the appraiser (or grandfather.)  But if you are a coin collector, you say you collect coins, and you say you bought a coin for your collection, not that you collected a coin for your collection.

Comment: @phoog My coin collection doesn't have any coins at all, as yet.  But that's ok, since zero is a number.

Comment: A church takes up "collection" Sunday morning.  If, at the end, there is only one coin in the plate, is it not still a "collection"?

Comment: @HotLicks ~ Did you read my answer before commenting? Regardless of that, coming up with convoluted, imaginary situations mean nothing. Give me a few minutes and I will give you a flock of colourless green sheep all sleeping furiously. Such imaginings do not constutute a credible argument. Great -  in the specific context of a church they collect from the congregation and call this ritual 'the collection'. It might even have a single coin in it. But leaping from that to a universal rule that you can have a collection of one? Please... don't assume I am an idiot.

Comment: @RoaringFish - Don't assume that the average person is not capable of appreciating the generality of a concept such as "collect" or "collection".  Most people are capable of working and reasoning with language without the need for such pedantic limitations on the meanings of words.  They are perfectly capable of conceiving of a "collection" of only one item, and don't need an anal schoolmarm to tell them otherwise.

Comment: @HotLicks ~ then show me real life, widespread use of, for example, art collections of one painting. Real ones... not some silly imaginary thing. Since when has real-life usage been 'anal schoolmarm'? I realise you are sore because I am not idiot enough to accept your petty ah but-ery, but get a grip on reality. Dictionaries say a collection is more than one item because that is how it is in the real world.

Answer (score 3):

The English language is very varied, and saying "this is ungrammatical" is dangerous. In this case, the book is wrong.

The word "collect" has different meanings. My dictionary has six different meanings for the verb alone, plus an adjective ("I called my mother collect" meaning the mother paid for the phone call) and two nouns (collect = winning bet, and collect = a short prayer, in church use). One of the verbs would be quite commonly connected with "coins", one would be quite commonly connected with "a coin", and one could be used with "a coin" in a very hypothetical situation.

"Collect" is used for gathering together, and for systematically seeking and acquiring. People can collect stamps, coins, teddy bears, some rare people even collect husbands or wives. In that case someone collecting coins would say "I collect coins", not "I collect a coin". Even if they just started collecting and have just purchased their first coin, they would say "I collect coins".

"Collect" is used for calling for and taking away an item or items. I collect the children from school, or I collect a child from school. If I pick up a single coin somewhere, then I collect a coin. Not coins. Example conversation: "What did you do at Mr. Smith's house yesterday?" "I collected a coin". "Do you collect coins?" "No, I'm a debt collector". If the person picks up one coin, and not two or three or more, they say "I collect a coin".

You collect yourself (recovering from some shock), and you can collect a horse (bring its hind legs together), you can collect your hair in a pony tail, doesn't work with a coin.

"His car left the road and collected a garbage can". It hit and probably destroyed a garbage can. The coin shop owner might say (very hypothetically) "This idiot driver lost control of his car and drove straight into my shop; fortunately all the merchandise is usually in the back of the store, so he collected my store sign and one coin that was in the shop window".

If I heard someone say "I collected a coin" I would immediately think that this person called at some place and picked up a single coin, and not that they are a coin collector, or that they made a grammatical error.

Comment: The OP makes it clear (from the suggested allternative 'colect coins') that the context is collecting as a hobby, not collecting in the sense of 'fetch'. Nobody says "I have a collection of one painting". They say "I have a painting".

Comment: @Roaring Fish: At least as I understood the question, the book is claiming that 'collect' for a single item is always ungrammatical.  But as this answer and others make clear, the word has uses other than in the context of making a collection of something, where it is grammatical to collect a single thing.

Comment: @jamesqf ~ what makes you think it is saying always ungrammatical?

Answer (score 2):

Children often **collect objects** that mean something special to them, and  what started off as a hobby can lead to a passion. People collect all sorts of things and mementos, for example:

1. stamps ([How to collect stamps](http://www.wikihow.com/Collect-Stamps))
2. badges ([How did you collect badges](http://taylorswift.com/users/hljtI5gc/blogs/6181162))
3. mugs ([I collect mugs](https://www.pinterest.com/averebely/i-collect-mugs/))
4. movie posters “[Some people collect movie posters as a pure investment. Others collect posters because they love the movie](http://sticknobillsonline.com/pages/press).”
5. **coins** ([7 reasons to collect coins](http://7%20Reasons%20to%20Collect%20Coins))

This is what the OP's "book" was referring to. **A collection of** *stamps*, *badges*, *mugs* etc.  require the plural form if the noun is countable. See [Papa Poule's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314603/why-is-collect-a-coin-ungrammatical) answer

This does not mean that you cannot collect a single item. See also [Roaring Fish's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/314608/44619) answer. *Collect* when it means *fetch*, or *pick up* something is a different meaning. For example:

> After booking online, I can collect (pick up) my train ticket(s) at the railway station.

It does not mean I keep a number of train tickets at home.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Do you collect coins (as in have or make a coin collection)?

A: Yes, I like to collect a coin now and again.

(English is more robust and flexible than some people might think or allow.)

This answer deliberately kept short as an alternative to others, which some may find too long too read.

Answer (score 0):

The book is of course wrong when making that statement, even when focused on, say, the hobby of coin collecting.

> Jack and Jake sit a the lunch table at school and Jack takes all the
>   coins out of his pocket, puts them on the table, and sorts through
>   them.  Jake asks, "What are you doing?"
>
> Jack picks a single coin out of the batch, stows it in a different
>   pocket, then returns the rest to the original pocket.  "I collect coins,"
>   Jack says.
>
> Jake mulls that for a second and then asks, "What do you when you
>   **collect a coin**?"
>
> "I take it home and stick it in a coin folder," replies Jack.

The phrase "collect a coin" is unusual for sure, and not idiomatic in many situations, but, as is the case with many rare but "legal" English constructions, it's perfectly fine in an appropriate context.  One can pedantically argue that some other term such as "cull" should have been used in the above exchange, but, even if Jake had lugged along a copy of Roget's to consult at the lunch table, changing terminology in the middle of a conversation creates unnecessary confusion (as does stopping to consult the thesaurus).

There's nothing wrong with the term, so long as one appreciates that it's not generally "idiomatic".